# SQL nested case Statement for rounding

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

I have an SQL statement that selects 4 pieces of data.

First is a name(String).

The other 3 are numbers(floats).

I'm having issues adding a case statement that looks at the name, and based off the name, it applys rounding rules, there can be up to three rounding rules for each name, so the case statement would have to be nested?

How would I go about this?
Could you give an example?
Would be something like this

```
case name_field
        when name_field = apple then
             when apple < 5 then
                 round(apple)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Show us some data and/or give us the full logic.  You look you are on the right track already.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, Microsoft SQL??? There are some diffenrences in SQL between the bunch

Answer (score 0):

Could you post any details about your data or any issues you are having? You seem to be on the right page. Here's an example of a nested case statement which can be tested [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all).

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE 
    WHEN Country = "UK" THEN
        CASE
            WHEN City = "London" THEN "A"
            ELSE "B"
        END
        ELSE "C"
   END AS something
FROM Customers;
```